# WinSCP put to S3 bucket "folder" when path doesn't exist and user doesn't have access to list objects

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, winscp

Using the WinSCP client, how can I load a CSV file to an S3 bucket with the following conditions:

- The only S3 access I have is to put an object at this example path: **s3://my_bucket/folder1/folder2**
- This logical directory doesn't exist unless I load the file - When I upload my file a Lambda function is fired to move the newly uploaded file. So this directory only "exists" for a split second on putobject.

I'm trying to build a WinSCP script like so:

```
open s3://[my_id]:[my_key]@s3.amazonaws.com -rawsettings S3DefaultRegion="[my_region]"

put "[source_dir]/file1.csv" /[my_bucket]/[folder1]/[folder2]/
put "[source_dir]/file2.csv" /[my_bucket]/[folder1]/[folder2]/

exit
```

but this returns an error:

```
Connecting to host...
Access denied.
Access Denied
Connection failed.
```

I updated the open statement to include the bucket/prefix

```
open s3://[my_id]:[my_key]@s3.amazonaws.com/[my_bucket]/[folder1]/[folder2] -rawsettings S3DefaultRegion="[my_region]"
```

and get this error:

```
Connecting to host...
File or folder '[my_bucket]/[folder1]/[folder2]' does not exist.
Connection failed.
```

I simply want to load a file to `[my_bucket]/[folder1]/[folder2]` in the same was as this AWS CLI script, which works without issue:

```
aws s3 cp [source_dir]/file1.csv s3://[my_bucket]/[folder1]/[folder2]
aws s3 cp [source_dir]/file2.csv s3://[my_bucket]/[folder1]/[folder2]
```

Comment: Just as a technical note, S3 [doesn't have directories](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/using-folders.html): "folders" are just part of the filename, so `folder1/folder2/file.cvs` is, in its entirely, your file path on S3. There's no "making a folder" inside a bucket, either, nor is there such a thing as "trying to create a file in a folder that doesn't exist": if you have write access to the bucket, you can create any file path. Check your S3 permissions for the specific bucket you're trying to write to, and make sure the bucket's permissions are set to allow PutObject

Comment: I understand there are no folders, that's why I said `This logical directory` and `"Folder"` in the title. I also understand there is no "making a folder" inside a bucket, I didn't say there was. This is simply not true: "if you have write access to the bucket, you can create any file path". I have IAM permissions that limit access on PutObject to a specific s3:prefix  `/[folder1]/[folder2]`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the additional information about your IAM permission limits: please _put that in your post_ instead of only mentioning that after someone leaves a comment. And please include any other details you left out, too =)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I didn't leave it out... It's literally the **first** bullet point in the post.

Comment: And what does the `aws` CLI tool say? Because if that also says Access Denied, you're going to have to double check both your bucket settings and your IAM rules. (always a good idea to double check anyway, it's easy forget to change a bucket's own default access levels)

Comment: I didn't unintentionally leave out the error message from `aws cli` :) - There isn't one. It puts the object just fine as expected. This is simply a WinSCP loading to S3 question.

Comment: I didn't say you did, but right now all you're saying is what the equivalent `aws` call would be; you don't say that you _ran_ that, and that that worked fine, and that means that one of the first things people are going to ask you to do is run it, and see what it does.

Comment: It looks like you need to include the bucket name at the end of the `open` command, but not the folder names. See: [Connecting to S3 bucket and transferring files via Batch script :: Support Forum :: WinSCP](https://winscp.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=29366) and [Connecting to Amazon S3 service :: WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_amazon_s3). Some people also suggest using the automatic tool to create the script, see: [Scripting Upload Files S3? :: Support Forum :: WinSCP](https://winscp.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=27380)